# grant multiple roles access to specific admin menu item

Tags: user-roles, admin-menu, user-access, members, plugin-members

I am writing a plugin that offers an admin menu item which only a specific, custom user role ("customrole" in the example) can access. I have implemented this as follows, and it works:

```
function add_admin_menu() {
add_menu_page(
    'Custom-Plugin',
    'Custom-Plugin',
    'customrole',
    'custom-plugin',
    'init_custom_menu_page'
    );
}
```

The problem is that the administrator does not have the rights to access this menu item anymore; I would like administrators to still be able to access it, however (and the "customrole"-users). How can I achieve this?

I am using the ["Members"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) plugin to create custom user roles if that makes a difference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use Roles to handle permissions for your menu page. Instead, use capabilities, and then assign those capabilities to whichever roles should have access.

For example, instead of creating a `customrole` role, use a custom capability like `manage_custom_plugin`:

```
add_menu_page(
    'Custom-Plugin',
    'Custom-Plugin',
    'manage_custom_plugin',
    'custom-plugin',
    'init_custom_menu_page'
);
```

Now, using the Members plugin you can enter `manage_custom_plugin` into the "Custom Capability" box, and add it to whichever roles you need.

In code you would grant this capability to roles using [`WP_Roles::add_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_roles/add_cap/), like so:

```
$roles = wp_roles();

$roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'manage_custom_plugin' );
$roles->add_cap( 'editor', 'manage_custom_plugin' );
```

Just be aware that these functions write to the database, so should only be run once, on plugin or theme activation.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!